# Hacer consultas con ajax en tiempo real y enviar un dato a la vez

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Amigos gracias a todos los que me han respondido  mis dudas.
Mira necesito hacer una consulta con ajax en tiempo real pero  a su vez necesito enviar un correo que esta dentro de un input. Entonces en el siguiente codigo tenemos un input  con un id="txtbusca" que es donde escribo lo que voy a buscar. y a su vez hay un input con un correo que tiene un id="correo", este se llena con el correo de la persona que inicie sesion pero necesito enviarlo a la otra pagina llamada procesoajax.php.

```
<div style="width: 80%; float:right;text-align: end; margin: 12px;"  >
 
        <input class="btnbusqueda" id="txtbusca"   type="text" placeholder="Buscar " >
        <input type="text" name="name" id="correo" value="luishg20@gmail.com">
        <button id="txtbusca"  name="busqueda" class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Buscar</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

         $("#txtbusca").keyup(function(){


              var parametros="txtbusca="+$(this).val()
               var parametroscorreo="correo="+$(this).val()
              $.ajax({
                    data:  parametros, parametroscorreo,
                  url:   'procesoajax.php',
                  type:  'post',
                    beforeSend: function () { },
                    success:  function (response) {                 
                        $("#respuestabusqueda").html(response);
                  },
                  error:function(){
                       alert("error")
                    }
               });
         })
})
</script>
    
</div>
```

En la otra pagina tenemos el siguiente codigo que es el que hace la busqueda y la consulta es aqui  donde queremos recibir el dato del input que esta alli la busqueda funciona correctamente lo que no llega es el correo. Alli estamos atrapando el dato con la siguiente linea de codigo $correousuario=$_POST['correo'];  si esa linea recibe correo se llena el input type="text" name="correo" value="". Pero es lo que no hemos podido lograr.

```
<?php 
include('con_db.php');

if(isset($_POST['txtbusca'])){
    $correousuario=$_POST['correo'];
        $q=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['txtbusca']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE producto LIKE '%".$q."%'"; // Esta linea 
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $producto=$registro['producto'];
        $image=$registro['link'];
        $image2=$registro['link2'];
        $image3=$registro['link3'];
        $image4=$registro['link4'];
        $valor=$registro['valor'];
        $descripcion=$registro['descripcion'];
        $correovendedor=$registro['correo'];
        $ntienda=$registro['nombretienda'];
        $titulo=$registro['producto'];
        $ubicacion=$registro['Ubicacion'];
        $dftienda=$registro['nombretienda'];
        $codigopro=$registro['codigoid'];
       

                
                ?>
            

<!-- imagen -->
<button id="decorimagen"  type="button"  data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#compra" >
<div  class="card" style="width: 20rem; ">
  <img src="<?php   echo $image;?> " class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><?php    echo $producto;?> </h5>
    <input type="text" name="correo" value="<?php echo$correousuario?>">
   
    <p class="card-text"></p>
   
  </div>
<!-- anterior imagen -->

</div>
</button>





<style type="text/css">
    .modal-ku {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
   .modal-xlg {
      width: 120%; 
   }
}
</style>
   <?php
   include("produ.php");
                            

    }
}

    ?>
```

Comment: No entiendo completamente lo que estás preguntando. ¿Dónde está el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas amigos los resolvi de la siguiente manera el problema es que no me enviaba el correo del input.  asi que en la primera pagina puse este codigo.

```
<div style="width: 80%; float:right;text-align: end; margin: 12px;"  >
 
        <input class="btnbusqueda" id="txtbusca"   type="text" placeholder="Buscar ">

        <input type="text" name="correo" id="correoy" value="luishg20@gmail.com">
        <button id="txtbuscab"  name="busqueda1" class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Buscar</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

         $("#txtbusca").keyup(function(){ 
                var textob=document.getElementById('txtbusca').value;
               var parametroscorreo=document.getElementById('correoy').value;
               datos="correo="+parametroscorreo+"&textoe="+textob;
                      $.ajax({
                        url:'procesoajax.php',
                        type:'POST',
                        data:datos,
                      })
                      .done(function(res){
                          $('#respuestabusqueda').html(res)
                            
                      });

         })
})
</script>
</div>
```

En la pagina donde se reciben los datos coloque este otro codigo que al paso que va haciendo la busqueda a su vez va enviando el correo que este dentro de ese input.

```
<?php 
include('con_db.php');
$correousuario=$_POST['correo'];
$textob=$_POST['textoe'];
if(isset($_POST['correo'])){

        $q=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['textoe']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE producto LIKE '%".$q."%'"; // Esta linea 
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $producto=$registro['producto'];
        $image=$registro['link'];
        $image2=$registro['link2'];
        $image3=$registro['link3'];
        $image4=$registro['link4'];
        $valor=$registro['valor'];
        $descripcion=$registro['descripcion'];
        $correovendedor=$registro['correo'];
        $ntienda=$registro['nombretienda'];
        $titulo=$registro['producto'];
        $ubicacion=$registro['Ubicacion'];
        $dftienda=$registro['nombretienda'];
        $codigopro=$registro['codigoid'];
       

                
                ?>
            

<!-- imagen -->
<button id="decorimagen"  type="button"  data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#compra" >
<div  class="card" style="width: 20rem; ">
  <img src="<?php   echo $image;?> " class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><?php    echo $producto;?> </h5>
    <input type="text" name="correo" value="<?php echo$correousuario?>">
   
    <p class="card-text"></p>
   
  </div>
<!-- anterior imagen -->

</div>
</button>





<style type="text/css">
    .modal-ku {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
   .modal-xlg {
      width: 120%; 
   }
}
</style>
   <?php
   include("produ.php");
                            

    }
}

    ?>
```